# 'Only the owner can change permissions' option is not inherited to subfolders

Tags: google-drive, permissions

Recently I have tried to share a folder with subfolders using the 'Only the owner can change permissions' option (the option that appears at the bottom of the sharing dialog window).

The folder that I have shared was not possible to be re-shared by the new user (which was good). However, it was possible to re-share the subfolders of this folder by that user. So it seems like the 'Only the owner can change permissions' option is not inherited to subfolders.

For example if I have the following folders:

```
- Folder01
  -- Folder02
  -- Folder03
```

then if I share `Folder01` with the 'Only the owner can change permissions' option to UserB, then `Folder01` will not be shareable by UserB, but `Folder02` and `Folder03` will be.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

[image: Sharing settings modal window]
[image: Setting the permission]

Answer (score 2):

I spoke with Google Support about this today. It is expected behavior and you have to set this permission on other folders.

It may be possible to push these permissions using a script / drive API, however any new folders would not have that permission and the script would have to be re-run on a regular basis.

Personally I would prefer that the permission inherited to all subfolders and files.